# Selecting data from groups within a csv and appending data to text file

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, python-itertools

I have a problem which I do not know how to solve currently. I have a csv with the format as shown below. Now what i need to do is perform some match scenarios and append some text strings to a file.

```
x,classA,uniqueclassindicator1,1,125,21.8,1,5.22,
x,classc,uniqueclassindicator1,3,125,21.8,2,5.22,
x,classd,uniqueclassindicator2,1,125,21.8,,,
x,classe,uniqueclassindicator2,2,125,21.8,,,
x,classBa,uniqueclassindicator2,3,125,21.8,,,
x,classBc,uniqueclassindicator2,4,125,21.8,,,
x,classAd,uniqueclassindicator3,1,125,21.8,2,2.56,
x,classc,uniqueclassindicator3,2,125,21.8,1,2.56,
x,classD,uniqueclassindicator3,3,125,21.8,,,
x,classa,uniqueclassindicator3,4,125,21.8,,,
x,classn,uniqueclassindicator4,1,125,21.8,,,
x,classm,uniqueclassindicator4,2,125,21.8,,,
x,classt,uniqueclassindicator4,3,125,21.8,,,
x,classd,uniqueclassindicator4,4,125,30.8,,,
x,classa,uniqueclassindicator4,5,125,31.8,,,
x,classn,uniqueclassindicator4,6,125,30.8,,,
x,classq,uniqueclassindicator5,1,125,35.8,1,3.31,3.1
x,classqe,uniqueclassindicator5,2,125,21.8,2,3.31,3.1 
x,classS,uniqueclassindicator5,3,125,21.8,3.31,3.1
x,classK,uniqueclassindicator5,4,125,21.8,,,
x,classL,uniqueclassindicator5,5,125,21.8,,,
x,classG,uniqueclassindicator5,6,125,21.8,,,
x,classH,uniqueclassindicator6,1,125,35.8,1,2.89,2.25   
x,classF,uniqueclassindicator6,2,125,21.8,3,2.89,2.25
x,classP,uniqueclassindicator6,3,125,21.8,2,2.89,2.25
x,classY,uniqueclassindicator6,4,125,21.8,,,
x,classU,uniqueclassindicator6,5,125,21.8,,,
x,classR,uniqueclassindicator6,6,125,21.8,,,
```

***Throughout this example assume zero based indexing***

You will notice that in the csv there column 2 is the uniqueclassindicator and I need to perform the following for each class.

#### 1.

If column 3 & column 6 are 1, and for the same uniqueclass (different row) in column 3 & 6 are both 2 then produce the string:

```
   "text data text" (column [1]) #where row = 1# "text data" column [1] #where row =2# "text" (column[17])`
```

for example, in row 15 we have this exact scenario. So the string text string would need to read:
    `text data text classq text data classqe text 3.31`

In the above text string, "classq" was pulled from column 1 row column 15, "classqe" was pulled from column1 row 16 and "3.31" was pulled from column8 row 15.

Just to reiterate, the match that occured to produce this string is for uniqueclassindicator5 within this class both column 3 & column 6 matched (1-1 & 2-2)

#### 2.

Is the pretty much the same as 1, however it is when column 3 and column 6 are 1,2 & 2,1. This occurs in uniqueclassindicator3 see row 7 as an example. So we would need to append the string:

```
text data text classc text data classAd text 2.56 #Note I have listed the class which had a 1 in column 16 first.`
```

#### 3.

This scenario is for when the 1,2,3 for column 3 for a given class matches the 1,2,3 for column 6, fortunately here we only need to return the 8 value in a string such as:

```
test data test data (column[8]) test data test
```

#### 4

like scenario 2 is when the same thing happens but not in the correct order. So if column 3 for a given uniqueclassinidcator =1-3 and column 6 = 1-3 (with the exception of scenario 3 just descibed.) Then create the following string.

```
data data (column[8]) data data.
```

I know the code required to do this is not the most simple, but if anyone could help me achieve this I would be very much in their debt. If anything is not clear please do not hesitate to contact me. Many thanks SMNALLY

#### Edit - Upon running code supplied by Martijn Pieters

I attempted to run the following code to match objectives 1,2 & 3. Whilst I can get objectives 1 & 2 working easy enough. I could not get Objective 3 to work.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

# you probably can think up better names
fields = ('x', 'class', 'indicator', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8')

entries = defaultdict(list)

with open('test.csv', 'rb') as fd:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fd, fields)

    for row in reader:
        # each row is now a dictionary
        # make your numbers, numbers
        for field in fields[3:]:
            row[field] = row[field] and float(row[field])

        previous = entries[row['indicator']]
        for p in previous:

            ##Objective 1
            if (row['col3'], row['col6']) == (2, 2) and (p['col3'], p['col6']) == (1, 1):
                print 'text {p[class]} text {r[class]} text {r[col7]}'.format(p=p, r=row)
            # etc, testing againts previous rows with the same indicator
            ##Objective 2
            if (row['col3'], row['col6']) == (2, 1) and (p['col3'], p['col6']) == (1, 2):
                print 'data {p[class]} & {r[class]} data {r[col7]}'.format(p=p, r=row)
            ##Objective 3
            if (row['col3'], row['col6']) == (3, 3) and (p['col3'], p['col6']) == (2, 2) and (p['col3'], p['col6']) == (1, 1):
                print 'text data text data {r[col8]}'.format(p=p, r=row)     

        # remember this row for later rows to match against.
        previous.append(row)
```

Can you anyone tell me what I have done wrong for objective 3? I recieved no traceback but also recieved no text strings.

Comment: Your description is really hard to follow because of the size of the data (its hard to see at a glance what "column 6 & 16" or "row 15" are). Can you cut your example data down to just the essential rows and columns for your examples? Also, try to be consistent about zero- or one-based indexing!

Comment: Hi I will cut it down, can you tell me what zero- or one-based indexing is ? Many thanks SMNALLY

Comment: Basically zero- or one-based indexing is about how you're describing the columns and rows, and what the first one is called. A value in "column 2" in your text (where you seemed to be using 1-based indexing) is `row[1]` in zero-based indexing code. You seemed to be mixing both styles (starting with zero or starting with one) in your text, so it was very hard to tell what you were referring to at any given point.

Comment: Ahh yeh, this is something that has annoyed me about python, since in the code column 0 would be column 1 if you opened the .csv in excel.

Comment: If you use a `csv.DictReader` and either provide row names yourself or put a header the first row CSV file, you'll be able to refer to column values by name, rather than by index. That might be easier for you. Python, like most modern programming languages, generally does zero-base indexing everywhere, so you could just as easily say that it's Excel that's the oddball here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, started off in vba coding switched to python since tasks have become to big for excel to handle. Slowly learning it mainly by reverse engineering other peoples working code and applying it to me needs. :)

Comment: This will be a two level for loop with three conditions. If you would explain your condition more clearly, I can try to write something up for you. I cannot understand your conditions right now. Main thing: the column indexes differ too much, it's not only shifting by one.

Comment: Hi Mai, I will gladly award a 50 point bounty to any answer that solves this problem. I have added more detail to scenario 1 (and fixed a mistake.) Im pretty sure that if anyone grasps scenario 1 then the rest are all pretty similar and straight forwards enough to understand. Many thanks SMNALLY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store information keyed by column 2 in a dictionary for easy lookup; for each unique column value keep a list of entries to match against later on.

A `collections.defaultdict()` object makes the first part easy. I'd use `csv.DictReader()` to give each column a meaningful name; instead of mentally having to map each column number to a meaning, the columns then have names, much easier to track:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

# you probably can think up better names
fields = ('x', 'class', 'indicator', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8')

entries = defaultdict(list)

with open(filename, 'rb') as fd:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fd, fields)

    for row in reader:
        # each row is now a dictionary
        # make your numbers, numbers
        for field in fields[3:]:
            row[field] = row[field] and float(row[field])

        previous = entries[row['indicator']]
        for p in previous:
            if (row['col3'], row['col6']) == (2, 2) and (p['col3'], p['col6']) == (1, 1):
                print 'text data text {p[class]} text data {r[class]} text {r[col8]}'.format(p=p, r=row)
            # etc, testing againts previous rows with the same indicator

        # remember this row for later rows to match against.
        previous.append(row)
```

This just matches your first scenario, but the other scenarios are just as easy to match.

This should be efficient enough if the number of entries *per unique class indicator* is low. If you run into hundreds (or worse) of rows per indicator, you need to start looking into efficient matching structures *per scenario* (as they match in different ways), to speed up lookups. This will probably require more memory, trading memory for increased speed.

Testing the above against your input dataset prints:

```
text data text classq text data classqe text 3.1
```

Adjusting the code to support unique `(col3, col6)` tuples:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

# you probably can think up better names
fields = ('x', 'class', 'indicator', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8')

entries = defaultdict(dict)

with open(filename, 'rb') as fd:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fd, fields)

    for row in reader:
        # each row is now a dictionary
        # make your numbers, numbers
        for field in fields[3:]:
            row[field] = row[field] and float(row[field])

        key = (row['col3'], row['col6'])
        previous = entries[row['indicator']]

        # scenario 1
        if key == (2, 2) and (1, 1) in previous:
            p = previous[(1, 1)]
            print 'text data text {p[class]} text data {r[class]} text {r[col8]}'.format(p=p, r=row)

        # scenario 3
        if key = (3, 3) and (1, 1) in previous and (2, 2) in previous:
            print 'text data text data {r[col8]}'.format(r=row)

        # remember this row for later rows to match against.
        previous[key] = row
```

Comment: This method could prove insainly useful to me, many thanks for introducing it to me

Comment: With regards to the efficiency the number of rows within each unique class indicators should never be greater than 50 :)

Comment: If the combination of `(col3, col6)` per `indicator` is unique, you can use a dictionary instead of a list too. Then you can look up pairs directly instead of looping.

Comment: Hi Martin, on trying to get this code to work, i recieve no traceback but also no prints. I am using the code above on a test csv of the exact data provided. Any ideas? Thanks SMNALLY

Comment: @SMNALLY: adjusted; there were two problems: the numeric columns were still strings, but we compared them with integers, and the because we are looking *back* across previously read rows, we needed to test the row against `(2, 2)` and look back for a row with `(1, 1)`, not the other way around.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters thanks for the edit, I have updated the question with my attempt to get objective 3 working. Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: @SMNALLY: You are looping over previous rows, but try to match against *two different* previous rows. I asked you before if the `(col3, col6)` tuples are unique. How much do you need to rely on the order of preceding rows as well? If they are unique (or it doesn't matter if later rows shadow previous rows) and order doesn't matter, then the code can use a nested dictionary keyed on `(col3, col6)` and you can simply see if `(1, 1)` and `(2, 2)` are a keys in that dictionary if your current row has `(3, 3)`.

Comment: `(col3, col6)` tuples are unique (if i understadand you correctly). And yes i need to simply see if `(1, 1)` and `(2, 2)` are a keys in that dictionary if the current row has `(3, 3.)` And then for objective 4, i can make matches for the differnt combinations that can occur. What is incorrect in the objective 3 that I have added?

Comment: @SMNALLY: Updated to use a dictionary per indicator; this makes matching scenarios easier; I've included scenario 3 in this example. Your version (against the list) made the mistake of trying to match `p` against two different scenarios. `previous` is a list, `p` *one* of the previous rows in that list, that one row cannot be both `(1, 1)` and `(2, 2)` at the same time. You'd have to search through `previous` differently if you need to match multiple previous rows.

Comment: Thanks everso much Martjin, I am still learning and I cant tell you how much playing and editing bits of code like this helps. It introduces me to new ideas & methodologies which I can add to my 'coding portfolio' if you know what i mean. Will have a play now :)

Comment: Just want to add one last thankyou, using this template I have made and edited the functions to over 300 lines of code. Performing about 50 different matches, with associated outputs.